# How to redirect a user to login page when session expires in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

Is there any means by which you can redirect a user to the login page once the session expires in `drupal 6`.Now when the session expires I get a message `"Access denied.You are not authorized to access this page."`.I really don't want this message to be shown ,rather it would be much better if i could redirect them to the login page.Could someone please help me..

Comment: Why not try http://drupal.stackexchange.com specialized community for drupal

Comment: Is there any module which you are using for expiring session ?

Comment: @RajeevK. no i have'nt used any contributed modules.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick trick:

Add following code to the very top of your page template file (page.tpl.php):

```
global $user; 
if (!$user->uid && $title == 'Access denied') { 
    header('Location: /user?destination=' . substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)); 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is only available on apache. Use Drupal's [`request_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/6) function instead (which also strips the leading slash for you so you can skip the `substr()` too).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can overwrite function:**template_process_page()** in your theme **template.php**.

here you can check global $user,to check is **$user->uid**,if it is equal 0,use function **drupal_goto()**,to the page you want

Answer (score 0):

[There is a module for that.](https://drupal.org/project/r4032login) 
Just install this module. It will replace the classic Access Denies page with the login form.

Comment: Other than including another module,could it be performed by some other manner..??is it a good idea editing the common.inc file in the includes folder.??

Comment: No it's not a good idea to edit common.inc, why don't you want to use this module ?

Comment: tanx for the info @RajeevK.just curious if i could override this effect other than by using a contributed module .. :)